# trying to filter a Kendo gird column that has a format

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, grid, format

I have a Kendo grid with a numeric column with a format to only show 1 decimal place.  The grid correctly rounds up or down and displays the correct number of decimals.  The issue I'm having is that if I try to filter on this column, the filter is using the actual value in the dataset and not the rounded display value.  So for e.g. if the dataset has a value of 11.61 the value will be displayed as 11.6.  If I use 11.6 in the filter with an equals, the grid displays no records.  I have to type in 11.61 to get the filter to work correctly.  I have created an example of dojo that shows this in action.  http://dojo.telerik.com/@elyons_nic/iyuPO

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to round the numbers in your dataset instead of rounding them on the client side.  You can also send both the raw and the rounded value to the client side if you need to work with both of them (display only the rounded column to the user).

Another option would be to implement your own dataSource filtering logic.  Strangely, kendo documentation is referring to [filter operator](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter.operator) as a string only and doesn't seems to allow (officially) a function.  However, if you google for it, you'll find out that many people have successfully created their own logic (see this [blog](http://blog.falafel.com/kendo-ui-custom-datasource-filtering/))

Basically, you'll have to set the filter manually like this:

```
dataSource.filter([{
    field: 'YourField',
    operator: function (dataItem, filterValue) {
        //Untested... just make sure to return true if the dataItem match your custom filter logic
        return filterValue.toFixed(1) == dataItem;
    },
    value: 16.1
}]);
```

The main challenge would be to find the right event to replace the filter created by the user with the your own filter.